# Can't download Maven dependency: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to generate a .jar file from my Maven project but I'm getting an error for a concrete dependency in my pom.xml:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.liferay.ant.bnd</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.41</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

So here's the error it shows when I try to package the project:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------< XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX >-------------
[INFO] Building XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/biz/aQute/bnd/bnd-plugin-parent/3.3.0/bnd-plugin-parent-3.3.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.819 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-12T12:30:07+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0: Could not transfer artifact biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:pom:3.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:276)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:253)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:pom:3.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin:pom:3.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:856)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:630)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:207)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:153)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.getResponse(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:626)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:571)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:452)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:303)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 64 more
```

I don't know what could be causing this, as my project has more dependencies and plugins which don't fail when packaging the project.

These are the things I came across on Stackoverflow, but they don't seem to work:

- Update Maven Project
- Force maven updates & restarting Eclipse
- Configuring corporate proxy

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as you said you tried restarting eclipse, i guess that you are trying to build your project from inside eclipse. 
have you tried building your project from the command line via maven? if so, does the same error occur?

Comment: In order to do what you said, do I have to install Maven on my pc? I guess right now I'm using the Eclipse integrated version. It's just that I have to ask for permissions to the administrator if I want to install new software.

Comment: Installation per se is not required. Downloading and unzipping maven as well as adding it to your path however is. 
Adding the maven installation to your path can be circumvented by calling maven from your project directory with the full path to maven, e.g. 

open commandline/terminal where your project is locatated. use for example: 
`C:\\path-to-extracted-maven\bin\mvn clean install`

Comment: Hey @meaningqo, I tried using maven from the command line but still got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it was my company's internet fault...

I switched to another network and could download dependencies with no problem.