# mvn package runs locally but fails in docker build with exit code 1

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

`mvn package` on my Spring-Boot application funs fine but when I do `docker build -t my-rest-api-1.0 .` using the below Dockerfile, I get `executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn package]: exit code: 1`.

As per my understanding `exit code 1` comes when there is some issue with the application, e.g compilation issues. But in my case `mvn package` is working fine independently.

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official maven/Java 8 image to create a build artifact.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/maven
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Build a release artifact.
RUN mvn package

# Use AdoptOpenJDK for base image.
# It's important to use OpenJDK 8u191 or above that has container support enabled.
# https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-slim

# Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /app/target/my-rest-api-*.jar /my-rest-api.jar

# Run the web service on container startup.
ENTRYPOINT java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /my-rest-api.jar
```

error logs (*90% of download logs I removed from here*):

```
~/folder docker build -t my-rest-api-1.0 .
[+] Building 351.6s (12/14)                                                                                                                                                   
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-11@sha256:1d29ccf46ef2a5e64f7de3d79a63f9bcffb4dc56be0ae3daed5ca5542b38aa2d                                        0.0s
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-11@sha256:1d29ccf46ef2a5e64f7de3d79a63f9bcffb4dc56be0ae3daed5ca5542b38aa2d                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                        0.1s
[+] Building 351.7s (12/14)                                                                                                                                                   
 => [auth] adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [auth] library/maven:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-11@sha256:1d29ccf46ef2a5e64f7de3d79a63f9bcffb4dc56be0ae3daed5ca5542b38aa2d                                        0.0s
[+] Building 542.3s (13/14)                                                                                                                                                   
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 175B                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-slim                                                                                            4.2s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-11                                                                                                      4.2s
 => [auth] adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => [auth] library/maven:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-11@sha256:1d29ccf46ef2a5e64f7de3d79a63f9bcffb4dc56be0ae3daed5ca5542b38aa2d                                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 48.45kB                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-slim@sha256:977e5664190cee429390298503e8bc9028cdeff9ade8df36f4e6e62d329aee42                              0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/5] COPY pom.xml .                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [builder 4/5] COPY src ./src                                                                                                                                         0.3s
 => ERROR [builder 5/5] RUN mvn package                                                                                                                                537.2s
------
 > [builder 5/5] RUN mvn package:
#13 5.583 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
#13 6.609 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.3.pom (8.6 kB at 4.9 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom (4.8 kB at 7.7 kB/s)
#13 19.39 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc-bom/21.1.0.0/ojdbc-bom-21.1.0.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc-bom/21.1.0.0/ojdbc-bom-21.1.0.0.pom (12 kB at 17 kB/s)
#13 20.13 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/prometheus/simpleclient_bom/0.10.0/simpleclient_bom-0.10.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/prometheus/simpleclient_bom/0.10.0/simpleclient_bom-0.10.0.pom (4.9 kB at 6.5 kB/s)
#13 20.91 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/prometheus/parent/0.10.0/parent-0.10.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/prometheus/parent/0.10.0/parent-0.10.0.pom (7.5 kB at 12 kB/s)
#13 21.80 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/r2dbc/r2dbc-bom/Arabba-SR10/r2dbc-bom-Arabba-SR10.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/r2dbc/r2dbc-bom/Arabba-SR10/r2dbc-bom-Arabba-SR10.pom (4.3 kB at 5.1 kB/s)
#13 22.79 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bom/2020.0.9/reactor-bom-2020.0.9.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/projectreactor/reactor-bom/2020.0.9/reactor-bom-2020.0.9.pom (4.2 kB at 6.2 kB/s)
#13 23.49 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/rsocket/rsocket-bom/1.1.1/rsocket-bom-1.1.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/rsocket/rsocket-bom/1.1.1/rsocket-bom-1.1.1.pom (2.6 kB at 4.0 kB/s)
#13 24.16 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-bom/2021.0.3/spring-data-bom-2021.0.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-bom/2021.0.3/spring-data-bom-2021.0.3.pom (5.7 kB at 9.3 kB/s)
#13 24.79 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.3.9/spring-framework-bom-5.3.9.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.3.9/spring-framework-bom-5.3.9.pom (5.6 kB at 7.4 kB/s)
#13 25.57 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-bom/5.5.2/spring-integration-bom-5.5.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-bom/5.5.2/spring-integration-bom-5.5.2.pom (9.1 kB at 13 kB/s)
#13 26.29 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-bom/5.5.1/spring-security-bom-5.5.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-bom/5.5.1/spring-security-bom-5.5.1.pom (5.7 kB at 8.7 kB/s)
#13 26.96 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2021.0.1/spring-session-bom-2021.0.1.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2021.0.1/spring-session-bom-2021.0.1.pom (2.7 kB at 4.6 kB/s)
#13 27.63 [INFO] 
#13 27.64 [INFO] ----------------------< com.my:my-rest-api >----------------------
#13 27.64 [INFO] Building my-rest-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
#13 27.64 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
#13 27.65 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.5.3/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.5.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.5.3/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.5.3.pom (3.1 kB at 3.8 kB/s)
#13 28.52 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.5.3/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.5.3.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.5.3/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.5.3.jar (102 kB at 74 kB/s)
#13 29.95 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.2.0/maven-resources-plugin-3.2.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.2.0/maven-resources-plugin-3.2.0.pom (8.1 kB at 13 kB/s)
#13 30.60 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/34/maven-plugins-34.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/34/maven-plugins-34.pom (11 kB at 16 kB/s)
#13 31.27 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/34/maven-parent-34.pom
#13 381.1 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
#13 393.2 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53recoverycontrolconfig/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-route53recoverycontrolconfig-1.12.37.jar
#13 393.2 Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar (28 kB at 361 B/s)
#13 393.2 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53recoveryreadiness/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-route53recoveryreadiness-1.12.37.jar
#13 393.2 Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/imgscalr/imgscalr-lib/4.2/imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar (28 kB at 360 B/s)
#13 393.2 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-proton/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-proton-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/jmespath-java/1.12.37/jmespath-java-1.12.37.jar (28 kB at 354 B/s)
#13 393.5 Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53recoverycluster/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-route53recoverycluster-1.12.37.jar (70 kB at 903 B/s)
#13 393.5 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-applicationcostprofiler/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-applicationcostprofiler-1.12.37.jar
#13 393.5 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-apprunner/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-apprunner-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53recoverycontrolconfig/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-route53recoverycontrolconfig-1.12.37.jar (319 kB at 4.1 kB/s)
#13 394.3 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssmcontacts/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-ssmcontacts-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-applicationcostprofiler/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-applicationcostprofiler-1.12.37.jar (105 kB at 1.3 kB/s)
#13 394.4 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssmincidents/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-ssmincidents-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53recoveryreadiness/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-route53recoveryreadiness-1.12.37.jar (446 kB at 5.7 kB/s)
#13 394.4 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-finspacedata/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-finspacedata-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-apprunner/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-apprunner-1.12.37.jar (373 kB at 4.7 kB/s)
#13 394.6 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-finspace/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-finspace-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-proton/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-proton-1.12.37.jar (716 kB at 9.1 kB/s)
#13 394.9 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-nimblestudio/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-nimblestudio-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-finspacedata/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-finspacedata-1.12.37.jar (80 kB at 1.0 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lookoutequipment/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-lookoutequipment-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-finspace/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-finspace-1.12.37.jar (120 kB at 1.5 kB/s)
#13 395.2 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-mgn/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-mgn-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssmincidents/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-ssmincidents-1.12.37.jar (483 kB at 6.1 kB/s)
#13 395.3 Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssmcontacts/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-ssmcontacts-1.12.37.jar (369 kB at 4.6 kB/s)
#13 395.3 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-fis/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-fis-1.12.37.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lookoutmetrics/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-lookoutmetrics-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lookoutequipment/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-lookoutequipment-1.12.37.jar (363 kB at 4.5 kB/s)
#13 396.4 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lexmodelsv2/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-lexmodelsv2-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-fis/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-fis-1.12.37.jar (305 kB at 3.8 kB/s)
#13 396.6 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-lexruntimev2/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-lexruntimev2-1.12.37.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-mgn/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-mgn-1.12.37.jar (511 kB at 6.3 kB/s)
#13 396.6 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-wellarchitected/1.12.37/aws-java-sdk-wellarchitected-1.12.37.jar
Progress (3): 698 kB | 496 kB | 0/1.2 MB| 0/1.2 MB
#13 396.6 [output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn package]: exit code: 1
```

I also noticed a weird situation. I tried it on three networks. Two in india and one in UK. Only one from India make this build.

How can I debug the actual error? I tried `mvn package -X` but that also didn't print actual error.

I tried `docker buildx build -t my-rest-api-0.1 .` and here is what I got

```
Failed to execute goal on project my-rest-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my:my-rest-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.5.3 -> org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final -> com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml:oss-parent:pom:35 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/35/oss-parent-35.pom: Remote host terminated the handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

and sometimes this

```
 Failed to execute goal on project my-rest-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my:my-rest-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.3..........................
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-models:jar:1.12.37: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.5.3/spring-boot-2.5.3.jar from central failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1,392,390; received: 1,344,040) -> [Help 1]
```

So I am blaming my internet provider here, because the same issue can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564127/4691230

But the question remains the same, why `mvn package` running locally but not with `docker`

Comment: Did you try to `docker exec` interactively in the container to get more details?

Comment: Run the container and run the build manually inside it so you can see all the output and debug what’s doing on.

Comment: Also, why _copy_ the src and pom when you can just mount it (with `ro`)?

Comment: Your Dockerfile comments mention using java8 at the top but is using java11 base images. Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: can you try using buildx as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819424/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-log-size-in-docker-when-building-a-container)?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson by bad at comments. 11 is supposed to be used.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I tried `buildx` some days back but after the build success I didn't find the image

Comment: @TheCoder that's kinda weird... did you give it a new unique tag?  and even if you cant find it, was it helpful in getting more log output to understand what seemed to be the issue during the build process?

Comment: @BoristheSpider What do you mean by 'run build manually'?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli `buildx` printed the error. Somehow a dependency is failing to resolve. Updated the question details

Comment: @TheCoder Thats kind of good news... please post it as an answer and accept it when you get a confirmation from your ISP

Comment: If it works outside of Docker I don't think the issue is your ISP, it's some network setting with Docker

Comment: @GaëlJ network setting has only one fields `docker subnet` set to `192.168.65.0/24`

Comment: @NoamYizraeli error is varying. Now I got `Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body` for a dependency

Comment: same dependency as with previouse problem?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli error stack is different each time

Comment: Due to previous experience with the last issue and this one mainly being caused by the backend serving the requests it still looks like something to do with the ISP or something along those lines

Comment: if you assuming that it's a fault of your isp you can try a vpn for that.

Comment: @tuhin47 using VPN did solved the issue. So it's definitely a network issue. But still confused why only on the docker? May be locally all the dependencies are cached in `~/.m2` and `mvn package` don't download them.